# Matrix exponentiation and ODE

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

We had this question on an ODE exam but to me it seems more related linear algebra. It goes like this: find all real matrices of the form $A= \left[ \begin{matrix}a&b \\c &0 \end{matrix} \right]$ so $e^{2 \pi A} =I$. 
I have tried finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors - an experiment that left me with $\lambda_1 =\frac{a+\sqrt{a^2 + 4bc}}{2}$ and its vector $v_1 = \left( \begin{matrix}1\\ \frac{c}{\lambda_1}\end{matrix} \right)$ and also $\lambda_2 =\frac{a-\sqrt{a^2 + 4bc}}{2}$ and its vector $v_2 = \left( \begin{matrix}1\\ \frac{c}{\lambda_2}\end{matrix} \right)$. This is as far as I got with this direction. 
 Another approach was to use Tailor series: $e^{2 \pi A}={e^{A}}^{2 \pi } = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^k}{k!} \right)^{2\pi}$ which didn't get me any further. I also tried to combine the to results to get the following: 
 $$ \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{A^k}{k!} \right)^{2\pi} =  \left( {\left[ \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 \\ \frac{c}{\lambda_1 } & \frac{c}{\lambda_2} \end{matrix} \right]} \left( \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{{\left[ \begin{matrix} \lambda_1 &0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{matrix} \right]}^k}{k!} \right) \frac{1}{c \left( \frac{1}{\lambda_2} - \frac{1}{\lambda_1} \right) } {\left[ \begin{matrix} \frac{1}{\lambda_2} & -1 \\ -\frac{c}{\lambda_1} & 1 \end{matrix} \right]} \right)^{2\pi}$$ And then I got totally lost. Help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is diagonalizable, there is a matrix $V$ such that
$$
                      A = V^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{cc}\lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2\end{array}\right]V
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
              e^{2\pi A} & = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(2\pi A)^{n} \\
                & = V^{-1}\left\{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\left[\begin{array}{cc}2\pi\lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\pi\lambda_2\end{array}\right]^{n} \right\}V \\
                & = V^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{cc}e^{2\pi\lambda_1} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{2\pi\lambda_2}\end{array}\right]V.
\end{align}
$$
The above is equal to $I$ iff $e^{2\pi\lambda_j}=1$ for $j=1,2$.

Answer (score 0):

You could use that, assuming unique eigenvalues, the matrix evaluation $f(A)$ of an analytical function $f$ and the polynomial value $p(A)$ have the same result if $f(λ_k)=p(λ_k)$ for all eigenvalues $λ_k$ of $A$.